# Find line intersection with all possible combinations of points in dataframe

Tags: python, sympy

let's say I have the following line:

```
l = Line(Point(25, 0), Point(25, 25))
```

and I have a dataframe (df) which contains 2500 points, something like:

```
    x   y
0   0   49
1   13  48
2   0   47
3   5   46
4   9   45
...
```

How can I *efficiently* examine if the lines formed by each and every combination of those points intersects with the above line?

Note that I am using the `intersection` function from the `sympy` library.

And note that using two nested loop takes forever... not efficient.

Comment: Is `l` an infinite line? Are the other lines infinite as well? Are all coordinates integer valued?

Comment: no it is not ... it starts and end on those two points

Comment: If the lines formed by points from the dataframe are also finite (bounded by these points), then it is impossible for all of them to intersect `l`. To see this, extend `l` infinitely and choose two points that are on the same side of this infinite line.

Comment: Do you want to find all pairs that intersect or do you want to determine whether all possible pairs intersect? If the latter then the answer is pretty much always going to be no per the comment above. Note also that SymPy's Line class represents an infinite line: you should use Segment for a finite line segment.

Comment: Thanks Oscar for the segment note ... and yes I want to "find all pairs that intersect"